# Arduino: using digital pins to emulate USB device

Tags: arduino-mega, usb

Is there any "easy" way to emulate USB keyboard or gamepad using digital pins on Arduino Mega? I looked at Uno-Joy/Mega-Joy, but I dont find firmware changes appealing.

Comment: No.  There is not anything like that.

Comment: @Delta_G - that's not really true.  It is possible, see V-USB.  But perhaps not "easy".  Reprogramming the ATmega8u2/ATmega16u2 on boards having that for their USB-serial interface is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

There is (or was) an implementation of software-only USB for the Arduino. I think it was called V-USB, though I am having trouble finding it now.

I think it may be [this library](https://github.com/gloob/vusb-for-arduino) though nothing has happened with that for a number of years.

Personally, I wouldn't recommend it, though, and would suggest using a board with a real USB interface, such as the Arduino Leonardo, chipKIT Lenny, or Teensy 3.x.

Comment: How much easier would it be with different hardware, say Leonardo?

Comment: Much easier. You just use the Joystick library: https://github.com/MHeironimus/ArduinoJoystickLibrary

Comment: Nice. However, there is one more problem: I am using Mega at the moment, because I need to read voltages off 8 different sources and make it to digital output. Is there any device that would have at least 8 analog pins?

Comment: Teensy 3.6, and you don't want the Joystick library - it has its own USB stack that works differently: https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_joystick.html

Comment: Thanks, but its a bit pricy, it would be cheaper to use two arduinos.

Comment: Or multiplex your analog inputs, or use an external ADC chip.

Comment: Right, didnt think about that. Leonardo it is, then. Also, according to arduino.cc, you can use some digital pins as analog pins.

Comment: Teensy 3.6 is probably overkill, check the number of analog inputs on the Teensy 3.2 or Teensy LC.

Comment: @VojtaDoležal You can get a Pro Micro for $4. It uses the same MCU as a Leonardo.